# yii check if user was redirected to login page

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to add something to the login view In yii, but I only want to do this if the user was redirected to that page by trying to access other controller/action.
Is there a way to know if the user was redirected or accessed the login link directly?

Comment: Please clarify your question so We can give you a suggestion easily.

Comment: so, if in my website if I go to a view that needs authentication in order to proceed, I am redirected to the login view. Or I can access the login view directly, either by typing the url for it or clicking in the login link.
Is there a way to know if i got to the login view directly or if I was redirected?

Answer (score 0):

@Pedro Salgado,

Here I am talking about Yii2,
So first you have to set config file in component array,

```
'user' => [
   'identityClass' => 'common\models\Users',
   'enableAutoLogin' => true,
   'loginUrl' => ['site/login-page'],
],
```

As per your setting,

Do following in your controller action where you want to do authentication,

```
public function actionDetails()
{
  if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest)
  {
     return $this->redirect(['site/login']);
  }
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Hi Sanhay, thanks for your answer, but that is not quite what I need. Let me try this with an example.
I have the controller/action account/dashboard, when I go to this url (without being authenticated), I am automatically redirected to account/login. This happens because of the accessRules function on the account controller, that I know.
What I need to know is how the user got to the account/login view, if it was by going to, for example, account/dashboard or if it accessed the account/login directly

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have already set up a `RequireLogin` or something similar, so I'll assume you've done so.

In your `RequireLogin` class you probably have something similar to this...

```
if(Yii::app()->user->isGuest && !in_array($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $allowedSites)){
    Yii::app()->user->loginRequired();
}
```

Add `Yii::app()->user->setFlash('redirected', true);` right before `loginRequired()`

Then, in your login view...

```
<?php if(Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('redirected'): ?>
<!-- stuff added here will only show up if redirected -->
<?php endif; ?>
```